# How do I apply a border-bottom to each line of a DIV so it has "lined paper" look?

Tags: html, css

My code:

```
div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    display:inline;
}
```

```
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

I want to have "lined paper" look. By now only area with text has bottom border.
Is it possible to have every bottom border to be at full width of DIV (even if text is only half or less of line width)?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dcV8Y/

Desired result:

http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/5159/linedpaper.png

Comment: I wouldn't add `border-bottom`, instead I would add a background image as a tile.

Comment: Could you please post an example?

Comment: The problem with a background image is that fonts on different systems might be slightly different sizes which would kill the effect. That or user styled content would kill it.

Comment: This does not matter as actually this technic will be used with inline images instead of text.

Comment: Maybe by adding a div container with 0 padding, 0 margin and a bottom border, although I could imagine there's a better solution than that.

Comment: Setting padding and margin to 0 does not make any change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lined-pages are usually created using a background image.

```
div {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/H8dFf.png');
  line-height: 24px;
  background-position: 0 -5px;
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/HvKVr/

I created the image by taking a screenshot of LibreOffice Draw, cutting of a square cell from it with only the bottom border of the cell visible in the image and scaling the height of the image to 24px using GIMP.

In this solution, I've shifted the lines 5 pixels up so that the text sits on the lines. If you do not want the text to sit on the lines but instead want it to be between them, you can omit the `background-position` property. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zuHn4/

Answer (score -3):

Why not a simple TABLE with n rows and just one fixed width column and CSS properties `border:thin;` and `valign:center;`?

Comment: How would you spread the text out to the different rows? How do you know in advance the value of n?

Comment: Tables should only be used for tabular data, which this isn't